# Crashlytics doesn't catch Out Of Memory

Tags: ios, out-of-memory, crashlytics

I use Crashlytics (3.8.3) and Answers (1.3.3). It catches all crashes except OOM crash.
I use next code for invoking OOM:

```
for (uint64_t jj = 0; jj < 100000000; jj++) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image.jpg"];
 }
```

App terminated when memory is low. But I don't see info about OOM crash on dashboard.

Why it happens? Why I don't see OOM event on dashboard?

Please write if somebody have the same problem or opposite you see OOM event on Crashlytics dashboard.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @rmaddy, yes, of course

Comment: Why it happens? Why I don't see OOM event on dashboard?

Comment: You should update your question as needed instead of posting comments.

Comment: Please see the docs on [Crashylitics and OOM](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/OOMs.html).

Comment: Yes, I have seen this

Comment: Same problem for me with Firebase Crashlytics - no reports for OOMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an app and I see OOM in crashlytics. It appears in fabric when selecting an application -> crashlytics -> last 7 days -> See details.

[image]